# Button not shown on metaio android

Tags: android, metaio

I'am setting up my first metaio sdk applicaton on android ,when I execute the proyect the camera image is shown in the main activity but if i add a button ,is not shown.
 This is the main activity code

```
package pfg.proyecto.com.proyecto;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity;
import com.metaio.sdk.MetaioDebug;
import com.metaio.sdk.jni.IGeometry;
import com.metaio.sdk.jni.IMetaioSDKCallback;
import com.metaio.tools.io.AssetsManager;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends ARViewActivity {

@Override
protected int getGUILayout() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected IMetaioSDKCallback getMetaioSDKCallbackHandler() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void loadContents() {

}

@Override
protected void onGeometryTouched(IGeometry geometry) {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LoadAssets().execute();
    boolean result = metaioSDK.setTrackingConfiguration("GPS", false);
    MetaioDebug.log("Tracking data loaded: " + result);
}


/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/

public class LoadAssets extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try
        {
            // Extract all assets and overwrite existing files if debug build
            AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            MetaioDebug.log(Log.ERROR, "Error extracting assets: " + e.getMessage());
            MetaioDebug.printStackTrace(Log.ERROR, e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

what I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

You need yo return the layout file in the getGUILayout method insted of return 0 just change the value to R.layout.the name of the layout XML file

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this
    protected int getGUILayout()
    {
        return R.layout.my_layout;
    }

and then add the button in my_layout